# iphone os 5 - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage

I have a bug.

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_message.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(47, 32, 47, 32) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];


UIImage *img = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_message.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(47, 32, 47, 32) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[imgView setImage:img];
[imgView setTag:99999999];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

And just meet os 5, os 6 and 7 pass.

```
//This is the error message
```

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd86c2c0'

i don't understand.
Anyone help me, please!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:]` is available only on or after iOS 6. (Reference: [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets%3aresizingMode%3a))

If you build app with this API in new Xcode, it will show you no warning or error. But when you run the app in iOS 5 devices, it will throw unrecognized selector exception. It is hard to catch such bug. So the best way to test is to run on the iOS 5 simulator / device.

It is a good practice too lookup documentation. Apple wrote the documentation well. You can also learn a lot by reading it.

Answer (score 1):

The variant with resizingMode was only added in ios6.  If you want to run under ios5 as well, you'll have to check whether that method is available.

Comment: Sure - just put in an if statement to decide if UIImage supports that method - so something like : if ([UIImage instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:)]) {  Do with resize } else { do something else }